# PHP array merge with keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

How do I merge these two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [uczrrtawpxfjanycwwlqygoq] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 53
        [value] => Boris
        [key] => uczrrtawpxfjanycwwlqygoq
    )

    [dreamhack] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 263
        [value] => More
        [key] => dreamhack
    )

)
```

And my second array which needs to be added to the keys of the first

```
Array
(
    [dreamhack] => Array
    (
        [viewers] => 32229
        [channel] => Array
            (
                [broadcaster_language] => en
                [display_name] => Dreamhack
                [_id] => 22859340
                [created_at] => 2011-06-09T06:11:52Z
                [updated_at] => 2016-08-14T18:34:36Z
                [delay] => 
                [banner] => 
                [background] => 
                [partner] => 1
                [views] => 36258931
                [followers] => 79892
                [_links] => Array
                    (
                        [self] =>
                        [teams] => 
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Doing a simple array merge gives the original array and not a combined one. So for dreamhack I would require one aeeay with all the tags combined [user_id], [value], [key], [viewers], [channel] and subarray.

Comment: did you try `array-merge-recursive` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as asked in the comment .. is this what you want ?

```
<pre>
<?php

$array1 = [
    'uczrrtawpxfjanycwwlqygoq' => [
        'user_id' => 53,
        'value' => 'Boris',
        'key' => 'uczrrtawpxfjanycwwlqygoq'
    ],

    'dreamhack' => [
        'user_id' => 263,
        'value' => 'More',
        'key' => 'dreamhack'
    ]

];


$array2 = [
    'dreamhack' => [
        'viewers' => 32229,
        'channel' => [
                'broadcaster_language' => 'en',
                'display_name' => 'Dreamhack',
                '_id' => 22859340,
                'created_at' => '2011-06-09T06:11:52Z',
                'updated_at' => '2016-08-14T18:34:36Z',
                'delay' => '',
                'banner' => '',
                'background' => '',
                'partner' => 1,
                'views' => 36258931,
                'followers' => 79892,
                '_links' => [
                        'self' => '',
                        'teams' => ''
                    ]

            ]

    ]

];

$result = array_merge_recursive ($array1, $array2);
var_dump($result);
?>
</pre>
```

result looks like:

```
array(2) {
  ["uczrrtawpxfjanycwwlqygoq"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(53)
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "Boris"
    ["key"]=>
    string(24) "uczrrtawpxfjanycwwlqygoq"
  }
  ["dreamhack"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(263)
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "More"
    ["key"]=>
    string(9) "dreamhack"
    ["viewers"]=>
    int(32229)
    ["channel"]=>
    array(12) {
      ["broadcaster_language"]=>
      string(2) "en"
      ["display_name"]=>
      string(9) "Dreamhack"
      ["_id"]=>
      int(22859340)
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(20) "2011-06-09T06:11:52Z"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(20) "2016-08-14T18:34:36Z"
      ["delay"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["banner"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["background"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["partner"]=>
      int(1)
      ["views"]=>
      int(36258931)
      ["followers"]=>
      int(79892)
      ["_links"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["self"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["teams"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: array_merge_recursive is what did the trick! Thnx for the very fast help!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php), which is specifically designed to do this sort of thing. To quote the docs:

> `array_merge_recursive()` merges the elements of one or more arrays
>   together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the
>   previous one. It returns the resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values for
>   these keys are merged together into an array, and this is done
>   recursively, so that if one of the values is an array itself, the
>   function will merge it with a corresponding entry in another array
>   too. If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later
>   value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.